# Azure Web Sites - publishing from on premises TFS ignores the publishing profile

Tags: msbuild, azure-web-app-service

I have successfully been able to publish to Windows Azure web sites by running MSBuild from the command line.

The command I execute is:

```
msbuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=azure /p:Password=thepassword /p:PublishDir=\\filesvr\DropLocation\ /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

When I run this command from my local machine from the command line it pushes the deployment to a windows azure web site. I can also run the command from the command line of the build machine and it works correctly. In both cases I am running the command from the directory of the web site project.

However when I create a build (based on the default template) and add the parameters

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=azure /p:Password=thepassword /p:PublishDir=\\filesvr\DropLocation\ /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

as MSBuild arguments of the TFS build, then the build completes successfully but does not publish to Azure. It does a standard web package and publish to the local file system. It does not seem to reference the publish profile at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was not working was related to some left over stuff in the csproj file namely:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <FilesToIncludeForPublish>OnlyFilesToRunTheApp</FilesToIncludeForPublish>
    <DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
    <DeployTarget>Package</DeployTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

should have been

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The packaging information probably got added when right clicking on the project and choosing publish. I assume it was causing the build to not deploy correctly as it was giving separate instructions to msdeploy.

The reason the publish was working locally was that it was building for the debug configuration that did not have these settings.